# Facebook data pull: how do I pull data before a specific date in python?

Tags: python, facebook, api

I need to pull facebook data on or before 4th August 2016. I have used

```
import facebook
user = 'nbcolympics'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')
feeds = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'feed')
```

But here I get all the posts and feeds. Is there a way to pull data which are before a specific date, say 4th August 2016? I am using Python for programming

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: @CBroe This is helpful, but how do I specify it in the python command.

Comment: For that you’ll have to check the documentation of whatever framework you are using.

Comment: @CBroe the timestamp could be added in the main function. I have added an answer below. Thanks for suggesting the documentation. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from CBroe, the timestamp could be added in the main command to extract data as per specific dates.

```
until_date_timestamp = int(datetime.strptime('04/08/2016', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime("%s"))
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts', until = until_date_timestamp)
feeds = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'feed', until = until_date_timestamp)
```

Here if we want to specify a start date as well, then it is

```
until_date_timestamp = int(datetime.strptime('04/08/2016', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime("%s"))
start_date_timestamp = int(datetime.strptime('01/01/2016', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime("%s"))
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts', since = start_date_timestamp,until = until_date_timestamp)
feeds = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'feed', since = start_date_timestamp,until = until_date_timestamp)
```